# What is the difference between handlebars and layouts in node using express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've got confused a bit recently over two terms. Handlebars and layouts. I looked it up and did not find proper answer. So, is it the same? If not, where does the difference lie? 
I was using handlebars and today found a video using layouts.
When using handlebars, I used the code below. Hovewer, with layouts, the code is different. Why? It's the same isn't it? I assume it is because in the app.use, the view engine is used in both. I'm really confused with this. I would be really thankful if you could explain that to me. Thanks again!

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs())
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')


app.use(expressLayouts)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

Comment: [EJS](https://ejs.co/) and [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) are two different templating systems. [`express-ejs-layouts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts) is one way to use EJS with Express. You can read what e.g. `app.engine` does [in the Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.engine).

Comment: Thanks, but at the end of a day they do the same job, don't they?